# How to create custom order confirmation email for admin in magento?

Tags: magento

i want to set custom email for admin on order confirmation.

and i try to change `Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()` .

evenif i write `exit;` in that function, doesn't change output.
that method is not calling
i have cleared history , 
so how can i solve that?
please help me out of this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe more exactly what you're trying to achieve. You are using `create`, `set` and `output` so I can't tell whether you want to create an extra email sent to the admin whenever an order confirmation email is sent to a customer/guest, and/or if you additionally want all confirmation emails having their specific layout depending on the receiver, or if you just want to have an admin's email address in CC/BCC whenever an order confirmation mail is sent, or whatever...

Answer (score 3):

Email templates for orders are available at `/app/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGES/template/email/sales.`Here you can customize a lot your emails.